# Unable to interact with cardano blockchain using cardano-wallet-js

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-node, cardano-address

My node is running on 6000 port. And cardano-wallet is running on 6002 port.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-6:~/cardano/testnet$ netstat -tuln | grep 6000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6000                 :::*                    LISTEN

ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-6:~/cardano/testnet$ netstat -tuln | grep 6002
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

But I unable create wallet using cardano-wallet-js. getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:6002 .

**********************Script*******************************
I am trying with below script. I tried using ('http://127.0.0.1:6002/v2') this url also but still unable to connect or do operation on cardano node using script.

import { WalletServer } from 'cardano-wallet-js';

const walletServer = WalletServer.init('http://0.0.0.0:6002/v2');
// const walletServer = WalletServer.init('http://127.0.0.1:6002/v2');

import { Seed } from 'cardano-wallet-js';

// generate a recovery phrase of 15 words (default)
let recoveryPhrase = Seed.generateRecoveryPhrase();

//For convenience, you can convert the recovery phrase into an array using this:
let words = Seed.toMnemonicList(recoveryPhrase);
// console.log(words);

let mnemonic_sentence = Seed.toMnemonicList(recoveryPhrase);
let passphrase = 'tangocrypto';
let name = 'tangocrypto-wallet';

let wallet = await walletServer.createOrRestoreShelleyWallet(name, mnemonic_sentence, passphrase);
console.log("wallet",wallet);

// List wallets:

let wallets = await walletServer.wallets();
// console.log("Wallets", wallets);

######################Error######################

<ref *1> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6002
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {